# Are those two phrase/sentence holding same meaning?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, learning

is:

"what chances are I have been cheated" similar to "what chances are I got cheated"??

Answer (score 2):

Both of the sentences you suggested don't actually make sense.  What you're looking for is:

> What are the chances I have been cheated?

and

> What are the chances I got cheated?

And, yes, both of these sentences mean the same thing, although the first is more formal-sounding than the second.

Comment: so you're saying if I flip around the "are" the sentence totally lose its meaning? I mean no one will be able to understand it?

Comment: People will probably be able to understand what you are trying to say, but it doesn't make grammatical sense, unfortunately…

Comment: 'Got' used in that way is _very_ informal.